# MongoDB recommendations for tree structure

Tags: mongodb, tree

I'm relatively new to MongoDB and have not worked with tree structures yet.

I need to create pedigrees. So normaly every dog should have parents. In some cases, the information about the parents are missing or not complete.

During my research, i came across this: [MongoDB tree with child references](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-child-references/)

Referring to this, my documents (shortened) could look like the following:

```
{
    _id: "123",
    name: "Foo",
    parents: [{father: "456"}, {mother: "789"}]
}
```

I would simply store the fathers and mothers `_id` in an array called 'parents'.

Right now i'm not sure, if my approach is correct or if i'm getting something completly wrong.
Can you guys give me recommendations on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a lot depends on how you want to access and modify the data. What you have done should work.

For example, if you always need to retrieve details of father and mother whenever you access Foo, you might want to store the entire parent object also.

I guess the main idea is store all the data that needs to be retrieved together in a single object. Dont try to normalize too much. If you see yourself normalizing , you are probably better off storing it in a relational database.